# Angularfire2 with firestore: delete specific fields from a document

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

As mentioned in the official documentation for web :

> To delete specific fields from a document, use the FieldValue.delete() method when you update a document:

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

// Remove the 'capital' field from the document
var removeCapital = cityRef.update({
    capital: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

I can't find a way to actually do it with angularfire2 (5.0.0-rc.3)

```
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

[...]

const cityRef = this.firestore.doc(`cities/BJ`);
cityRef.update({
  capital: this.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
});
```

> Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined

Comment: i am not sure just try `capital: FieldValue.delete()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are you miss the imports

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

now you can try

```
capital: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()
```

Comment: capital: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.delete();